# How can I conditionally copy over rows of column A to column B in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to copy column A to column B, but for certain rows of column A, I want to make a stringsplit change as it copies over to column B. Can I do this without using a for loop (namely, can I do this using mutate in dplyr)?

I want to split on ':' (if found) and take the 2nd element of the strsplit and put it in B.

Sample result:

```
    A B
1   a a
2   b b
3 c:d d
```

Comment: You can certainly do what you want without a loop. It would be helpful if you could provide some example data for what you're working with, the rule you would apply to A to identify rows that would get split, as well as an example desired output.

Comment: Try `dput(your_data)` and paste the results in your question.

Comment: Made some edits - apologies. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 2):

This honestly does not require big guns like `dplyr`, we split column A and take last element of the result

```
DF = read.table(text="A B
   a a
   b b
 c:d d",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


DF$NewCol=do.call(rbind,lapply(DF[,"A"],function(x) { z=unlist(strsplit(x,":")); z[length(z)] } ))
DF
#  A B NewCol
#  a a      a
#  b b      b
#c:d d      d
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `lapply` function:

```
DF = read.table(text="A B
   a a
   b b
 c:d d",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

DF$NewCol<-do.call(rbind,lapply(strsplit(DF [,'A'],split=":"), function(x) tail(x,1)))

DF
    A B NewCol
1   a a      a
2   b b      b
3 c:d d      d
```

Answer (score 2):

Hard to beat simple regex here:

```
df$B = sub('.*:', '', df$A)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
 dfrm$B[grepl("[:]", dfrm$A)] <- 
          sapply( strsplit( as.character(dfrm$A)[grepl("[:]", dfrm$A)], split="[:]"), "[", 2)
```

Translated into English that says replace only the B items where A has a ":" in it and do so with the second item of the list formed when those A items in the same row are split on the regex character-class containing only the ":" character.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
df1$B <- str_extract(df1$A, "\\w$")
df1$B
#[1] "a" "b" "d"
```